# Kendo switch change event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

is there any way ,to get the Change event of kendo switch with jquery?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="tst" aria-label="Notifications Switch"  />
```

the following does not work:

```
$("#tst").change(function(){
 alert("works");
});
```

Comment: is the html loaded in the DOM dynamically?

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR yes

Comment: You should show how the widget is initialized.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown what do you mean?im new in kendo

Comment: I mean your Kendo code.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown i thought whatever it is,im able to get the click event by what i have posted,but seems i am forced to use kendo helper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for dynamic elements you should use like this

```
$(document).on('change',"#tst",function(){
 alert("works");
});
```

Comment: and for static?

Comment: for static you can write like that only

Comment: you mean,what they say in kendo helper?

Comment: @mortezasol yes

Answer (score 2):

Some kendo controls, due to the way they are rendered, require the event to be placed on their data object.  This will fix your code.

$("#tst").data("kendoSwitch").bind("change", function () {
alert("works");
});